Are Failed Connections logged in IIS?
I have situations where we have web services deployed on customer sites and then encounter issues where clients fail to connect to them for reasons such as the port the service is running on has been blocked/not opened, certificate issues etc.
I'm try and trace the issues as in all cases these clients are app written by 3rd parties, I wanted to know if any logs or events would be created (these web services are running in IIS)?  My theory is if the connection fails then there would be no log of the event as the request would not reach the server.
Any suggestions?

Your theory is correct, for port/routing/network problems the request would never hit the host machine so you would need to look at firewall/router logs.  Many TLS/SSL errors are logged to the SChannel event log, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/enable-schannel-event-logging

Things like that belong mostly to the topic of Windows Server networking, and should be analyzed/investigated by server/network administrators who know much more about the overall picture. IIS itself just logs whatever related to its own internals (HTTP request processing).

IIS logs the requests that reach the server. If the port the service is running on has been blocked/not opened, you can try to use telnet to check the status of the port according to this document: telnet | Microsoft Learn.

Thank you folks, it was as I expected, but wanted some additional confirmation.
